# Is $M$ necessarily a submodule of $M\times N$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

Suppose $M$ and $N$ are Abelian groups and $M \times N$ is the direct product of $M$ and $N$.  Now suppose $M \times N$ is an $R$-module.  Are $M$ and $N$ necessarily submodules of $M \times N$?

$M$ and $N$ are subgroups of $M \times N$,
but is $M \times \{0\}$ closed the action of $M \times N$?

Is it the case the action of every $M \times N$ module has an action that acts on $M$ and $N$ component-wise?  This seems really simple to me, but I have been stuck trying to prove it.

Comment: Yes, $M\times\{0\}$ is a submodule of $M\times N$. Indeed $M'\times N'$ is a submodule of $M\times N$ when $M'$ is a submodule of $M$ and $N'$ is a submodule of $N$.

Comment: Maybe you can look at $\mathbb{Q}\times\mathbb{R}$ which is isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}$ as a $\mathbb{Q}$-vector space.  Then, you can (with the Axiom of Choice) equip $\mathbb{Q}\times\mathbb{R}$ with an $\mathbb{R}$-vector space structure.  However, from this construction, $\mathbb{Q}$ is not an $\mathbb{R}$-vector subspace of $\mathbb{Q}\times\mathbb{R}$.  (The only way to make $\mathbb{Q}$ an $\mathbb{R}$-module is with the trivial $\mathbb{R}$-action.)

Answer (score 1):

No, this is usually not the case.  For instance, let $R=\mathbb{Z}[x]$ and $M=N=\mathbb{Z}$.  Then the abelian group $M\times N=\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}$ can be made an $R$-module in many different ways: all you have to do is specify an endomorphism which is how $x$ acts.  For instance, one way to make $\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}$ an $R$-module is to say $x(m,n)=(n,m)$.  With this $R$-module structure, $\mathbb{Z}\times\{0\}$ is not a submodule.

Comment: While your answer is great, I have one remark.  I am not sure that the OP means that "$M\times 0$ is a submodule of $M\times N$" when he says that "$M$ is a submodule of $M\times N$."  So, I gave an example for which $M\times N$ has no submodule isomorphic to $M$.  (In your case, $\mathbb{Z}(1,1)$ is a submodule of $\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}$ isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}$.)

Comment: Thanks to both of you!  This is good to know.  As a note, when $M$ and $N$ are finite such that $|M|$ and $|N|$ are relatively prime, any action of an $M \times N$ module must act component-wise.  To see this, $(0,0) = r (0,0) = r (|M| m, 0) = |M| r (m,0) = |M| (m',n') = (|M| m', |M|n') = (0, |M| n')$, and if $|M| n' = 0$, we must have $n' = 0$, since $|M|$ and $|N|$ are relatively prime.